# Верификация нескольких, похожих приложений

Tags: ios, appstore

Хотелось бы понять, имеют ли шанс пройти верификацию несколько однотипных приложений, отличающихся дизайном и небольшими нюансами (перестановками кнопок)?
Впервые столкнулся с добавлением в Appstore, на руках есть:

1. 4 вариации приложения;
2. Сертификат разработчика;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сказал что риск весьма велик, хотя как повезет - могут и не просечь. А зачем вам 4 одинаковых приложения? Если они отличаются только контентом (перестановки кнопок и дизайн можно считать контентом в принципе) и хочется взять денюжку за все 4, можно попытаться оформить это как один основной скин\функционал и 3 дополнительных с помощью [In-App Purchase](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/)

Comment: Вы правы, идея здравая. 4 одинаковых приложения - для повышения продажной стоимости, буду использовать другой подход, спасибо.